# PHP preg_match_all RegEx conflict

Tags: php, regex

```
if (preg_match_all ("/\[protected\]\s*(((?!\[protected\]|\[/protected\]).)+)\s*\[/protected\]/g", $text, $matches)) {                                                
        var_dump($matches);
        var_dump($text); 
  }
```

The text is

```
<p>SDGDSFGDFGdsgdfog<br>
[protected]<br> STUFFFFFF<br>
[/protected]<br> SDGDSFGDFGdsgdfog</p>
```

But $matches when `var_dump` ed (outside the if statement), it gives out `NULL`

Help people!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're using `/` (slash) as the regex delimiter, but you also have unescaped slashes in the regex.  Either escape them or (preferably) use a different delimiter.
2. There's no `g` modifier in PHP regexes.  If you want a global match, you use `preg_match_all()`; otherwise you use `preg_match()`.
3. ...but there *is* an `s` modifier, and you should be using it.  That's what enables `.` to match newlines.

After changing your regex to this:

```
'~\[protected\]\s*((?:(?!\[/?protected\]).)+?)\s*\[/protected\]~s'
```

...I get this output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(42) "[protected]<br> STUFFFFFF<br>
[/protected]"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "<br> STUFFFFFF<br>"
  }
}
string(93) "<p>SDGDSFGDFGdsgdfog<br>
[protected]<br> STUFFFFFF<br>
[/protected]<br> SDGDSFGDFGdsgdfog</p>"
```

Additional changes:

- I switched to using single-quotes around the regex; double-quotes are subject to `$variable` interpolation and `{embedded code}` evaluation.
- I shortened the lookahead expression by using an optional slash (`/?`).
- I switched to using a reluctant plus (`+?`) so the whitespace following the closing tag doesn't get included in the capture group.
- I changed the innermost group from capturing to non-capturing; it was only saving the last character in the matched text, which seems pointless.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text= '<p>SDGDSFGDFGdsgdfog<br>
[protected]<br> STUFFFFFF<br>
[/protected]<br> SDGDSFGDFGdsgdfog</p>';

if (preg_match_all ("/\[protected\]\s*(((?!\[protected\]|\[\/protected\]).)+)\s*\[\/protected\]/x", $text, $matches)) {                                                
        var_dump($matches);
        var_dump($text); 
}
```

There is no `g` modifier in `preg_match` - you can read more at [Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) . Using `x` modifier works fine thou.